# R recursively get the name of the first element of a nested list of arbitrary depth

Tags: r, list, recursion, vector, lapply

I know there are plenty of related posts, but I found none of them that solved my issue. The situation is the following:
I am using the shinyTree package and when I select a node, its structure is the following

```
List of 1
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ ParentA:List of 1
  .. ..$ ParentB:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ ParentC: num 0
```

this can be reproduced:

```
mynode = list(list(ParentA=list(ParentB=list(ParentC=0)))
```

I would like to obtain from this a vector of the names of the nested list

```
c("ParentA", "ParentB", "ParentC")
```

I have tried to use recursive functions like

```
recursive <- function(x){
if(is.list(x)) recursive(x[[1]])
names(x[[1]])
}
```

with `lapply` but it did not work... I have no more ideas what to try... Could anyone help please ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive solution would be:

```r
recursive <- function(node) {
  x <- NULL
  if (is.list(node)) {
    first <- node[[1]]
    x <- c(x, names(first)[[1]], recursive(first))
  }
  
  return(x)
}

recursive(mynode)
#> [1] "ParentA" "ParentB" "ParentC"
```

---

Upsides? It won't fail regardless of the format of the names, especially if they have "." eg. `ParentA.A`.

```r
mynode <- list(list(ParentA.A=list(ParentB=list(ParentC=0))))
```

`strsplit()` would not give you the right answer here:

```r
strsplit(names(unlist(mynode)) , "\\.")[[1]]
#> [1] "ParentA" "A"       "ParentB" "ParentC"
```

But the recursive solution would work just fine:

```r
recursive(mynode)
#> [1] "ParentA.A" "ParentB"   "ParentC"
```

Comment: thanks a lot works perfectly !!! as you point out it works also with dots in the names - what can happen in my case

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
strsplit(names(unlist(mynode)) , "\\.")[[1]]
```

- output

```
#> [1] "ParentA" "ParentB" "ParentC"
```

Comment: OP only wants names for the first element. If the list contained 2nd element anywhere, this code would fail

Comment: +1. Sorry I did not see the `[[1]]` at the end which chooses the first name. THis will work. Probabbly you should remove the `[[1]]` that is within the code

Comment: That was confusing me , but i trust your answers .

Comment: The reason why it was giing the correct answer before is because the first name was `NULL` but if it was not null, then it would have skipped it altogether. This is now correct as it will not skip it. ie try `mynode2<- list(a=list(b=list(c=1)))` they try `unlist(mynode2[[1]])` and `unlist(mynode2)` and see the difference

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply; however not the most convenient solution in my case because I can have "." in the list names -> it  gets messed up with the strsplit

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package, which may be useful to handle multiple nodes in the nested list simultaneously.

```r
rrapply::rrapply(
  mynode, 
  f = function(x, .xparents) .xparents[-1],  
  how = "flatten"                      
)
#> $ParentC
#> [1] "ParentA" "ParentB" "ParentC"
```